# Prove that this function defined by f(x) is bijective.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that the function $ f: \mathbb{R} -  \{1\}  \to \mathbb{R} - \{1\}$ defined by $ f(x) $ is bijective. 
>   $$ f(x)=\left({x+1\over x-1}\right)^3 $$

I am taking my first Computer Science course in Discrete Math and coming from a non-math and non-programming background have found myself a bit overwhelmed with the content of the course. It's like basic algebra on steroids, so expect a lot of questions from me in the future!

Thanks to everyone who can help me out with this problem.

> I can prove that it is injective, but can't figure out how to prove if it is bijective or not.

Comment: You have to prove onto as well, to prove bijection. To do this consider $y \in \mathbb{R} - \{1\}$. Is there an $x \in \mathbb{R} - \{1\}$ such that $f(x) = y$?

Comment: So, if it is the case that there is a $y$ where $f(x)\neq y$, then the function is not onto, and therefore not bijective.
Since $f(x)\neq 2$, the function cannot be bijective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$ and we look for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$ such that
$$f(x)=y\iff \frac{x+1}{x-1}=y^{1/3}=\alpha\ne1\iff x+1=\alpha x-\alpha\iff x=\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha-1}=f(\alpha)$$
and this work prove that $f$ is surjective and in fact bijective and that 
$$f^{-1}=f\circ\sqrt[3]{}$$

Comment: Brain exploded a bit, but I'll spend the rest of tonight breaking apart your answer and figure it out. Thanks!